# Task Scheduler logs are partially restricted

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am working to exploit Task Scheduler logs to determine a timeline of jobs run at our site. Often we have to identify a job and we may only know the time the job failed. In such a case we begin searching servers and log files to find the job in question. To assist I've begun dumping logs and parsing them into a site timeline. It works well excepting task scheduler limits output with this message, 'There are no scheduled tasks presently available at your access level'. So how do I elevate privileges to get all job logs?

This is a sponsored project so one of our engineers will implement a method that works. I have thought of a push mecganism where an admin would auto-dump logs and I'll copy and parse.

TIA

I dump logs with 'schtasks /S server /Query /FO TABLE  /V /HRESULT'. Running from an elevated shell does nothing more and using production account credentials does not either.

Comment: This site is for programming related questions only. You're looking for [su] instead. You can find more information about this site in the [help].